# reset ant build.xml for run android test project

Tags: java, android, ant, eclipse-adt

i think i've edited something wrong in the ant build.xml that is imported during the steps in  [this site](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+an+Android+app+and+test+project)

and when i try to

```
ant clean debug
```

the task goes wrong. i'd like to know if is possible re-generate the build.xml contained into the eclipse adt boundle ant folder. 
Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project path and run this command:

> android update project --path .

That's it..

Comment: i know but if i do like this, it tries to import the build.xml from the /sdk/tools/ant/build.xml and that's is modified. i'd like to generate a new one in that path (/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml)

Comment: I think it is not possible to build new build.xml in /sdk/tools/ant/ this path. You can download new SDK from this link:http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: i've downloaded a new one how you suggested but doing ant clean debug the compiler says: build.xml:484: getbuildtools doesn't support the "verbose" attribute

Comment: i've simply deleted the unsupported attributes (many) and now works! thank's

Answer (score 0):

download the latest sdk tools from "http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html"
SDK Tools Only

ant-tasks.jar define the ant getbuildtools command,Your current version does not support verbose attribute, You can decompile ant-tasks.jar to see.